# Android studio 'view all attributes' loading wrong attributes

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When i click 'view all attributes' i am given wrong stuff that is not even attributes! Here are some screen shots of what is happening when i click view all attributes[image]

Comment: Actually i had to click the setting wheel next to the double arrows and click all attributes table and now it shows

Answer (score 0):

In your component hierarchy, select the view/activity. The attributes should show up then. It doesn't look like you've selected anything in this picture